# Login to another site with Windows Authentication without prompting the user

Tags: .net, windows, windows-authentication

I have this page http://www.mareez.com.sa/Camera1.htm. It asks for the Windows username & password. I want to hide this username & password, and I want to pass it to the camera server in my code (i.e. not visible to the website visitor).

Answer (score 0):

Than turn off Basic HTTP authentication on your web server and use impersonation for all anonymous users.

Comment: Well actually this is coming from another server. NOT my server.